# ActiveSheet().getName() returns different results. Could somebody explain why?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am trying to get my gsheet script to run on an activesheet in a specific document.

If I do;

`function get_name() {`

`let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();`

`Logger.log(ss);`

`}`

It returns name of whichever sheet is 'active', meaning if there are three sheets (sheet1, sheet2, sheet3) and I run the code when I am on sheet2, it will display "sheet2".

But if I do;

`function get_name() {`

`let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("idispastedhere").getActiveSheet().getName();`

`Logger.log(ss);`

`}`

It returns the sheet that is first in order. So say the order is (sheet1, sheet2 and sheet3) and I am on sheet2, it will return "sheet1".

Could somebody explain why this happens?